# pointer to an array derefferencing

Tags: c, pointers

following is a section of code that I have written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int (*p)[2];
    int a[2] = {0, 1};
    p = &a;
    printf("p = %x\n",p);
    printf("&p = %x\n",&p);
    printf("a = %x\n",a);
    printf("&a = %x\n",&a);
    printf("*p = %x\n",*p);
    printf("*a = %x\n",*a);
}
```

Following is the output which I got:

```
p = bfd387c8
&p = bfd387c4
a = bfd387c8
&a = bfd387c8
*p = bfd387c8
*a = 0
```

Now I have this doubt that how could p and *p be equal. Actually `p = a;*a = 0;`
then why *p is not equal to 0 also. Please this is my first question  at stack 
overflow.Please help me out.

Comment: you mean `int *p[2];` instead of `int (*p)[2];`?

Comment: Btw, you should use `%p` to print a pointer's value.

Comment: Note that to print pointers, you should use `printf("p = %p\n",(void*)p);`.

Comment: to pointer `p = &a;`, dereference `p` -> `*p` `&a` --> `*&a` --> `a` is not `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int (*p)[2];
    int a[2] = {0, 1};
    p = &a;
    printf("p = %p\n",(void*)p);
    printf("&p = %p\n",(void*)&p);
    printf("a = %p\n",(void*)a);
    printf("&a = %p\n",(void*)&a);
    printf("*p = %p\n",(void*)*p);
    printf("*a = %x\n",*a);
    printf("**p = %x\n",**p);
    return 0;
}
```

You should use `%p` and cast to `(void*)` to print pointer.

`p` points to the array `a` (which implies `a == &a`) and so `p == *p`. To get the first value of the array you have to use `**p` because it is an pointer to the array.

Comment: okay, but why should I do a (void*) to print the address.Well,thanks in advance.

Comment: because ´(*p)[0]´ is the first value and `p[0]` is a pointer to the array. `p[0]` has the same value as `*p` and `p`, all 3 point to the array or the first value of the array.

Answer (score 1):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you declare an array, it's laid out in memory like so:

```
          +---+
  arr[0]: |   |
          +---+
  arr[1]: |   |
          +---+
           ...
          +---+
arr[N-1]: |   |
          +---+
```

Notice that there's no separate `arr` variable to store the address of the first element of the array; the address of the first element is the same as the address of the whole array.

Thus, the *values* of the expressions `arr` and `&arr` are the same, but the *types* are different (`T *` vs. `T (*)[N]`).

Since `p` evaluates to `&a` and `*p` evaluates to `a`, and since `&a` and `a` yield the same value, then `p` and `*p` will also yield the same value.

`(*p)[0] == a[0] == *a == 0`